# Как подключить библиотеку/заголовочные файлы в gcc?

Tags: gcc, c, ассемблер

Есть исходники утилиты sstrip.c прописан headfile 
`#include   <asm/elf.h>` При сборке ругается на его отстутствие. В /usr/include/asm его и вправду нет. Сам файл находится по адресу: /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-31/arch/x86/include/asm Простое копирование в /usr/include/asm результата не дает - ругается на отстустсвие еще массы связных файлов. Как подключить этот каталог к gcc, чтобы программа нормльно собралась. gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3, 
makefile более чем простой:

```
sstrip: sstrip.c
        gcc -ggdb -Wall -W -o sstrip sstrip.c
 clean:
        rm -f sstrip
```

Comment: А ругается компилятор или линкер? и далее см. ключи -IDIR, -isystem DIR и пр. для поиска хедеров, -LDIR - директории для поиска библиотек (подключаемых по -lLIBRARY). Просьба не путать big-I (I) и small-l (l)

Comment: Ругается компилятор

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать создать makefile и указать каталог "/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-31/arch/x86/include/asm" опцией -C.
Вроде так.

```
      make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-31/arch/x86/include/asm
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить ключ -I/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-31/arch/x86/ в вызов gcc

Answer (score 0):

В UBUNTU можно выбрать ядро LINUX при загрузке. В загруженной первоначально версии ядра была урезанная библиотека "хедеров". Необходимые файлы лежали в другой версии ядра по адресу: /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-31/arch/x86/include/asm . Компилятор gcc по умолчанию подгружает **.h (хедер-файлы) из каталога /usr/include. Если они в дополнительной библиотеке (в данном случае /asm), то в файле-исходнике (sourse, он же** .c) указывается доп. каталог - #include <asm elf.h=""> . Самым простым решением вопроса оказалась смена ядра при загрузке UBUNTU на необходимую. Вариант копирования в каталог /usr/include/asm тоже возможен. У меня с первой попытки не получилось, потому что содержание самих "хедеров" отличалось. Пришлось искать другую версию ядра.